# How should I rewrite this constructor function to move methods from instance to prototype?

Tags: javascript

Good day everyone. So I have a function named Rect and I need to move methods from instance to prototype. I tried to do it. It seems to me that everything is correct, but nevertheless the code does not work from the word at all.

```
     function Rect(width, height) {
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
    
                this.getArea = function () {
                    return this.height * this.width;
                }
    
                this.getPerimeter = function () {
                    return this.height * 2 + this.width * 2;
                }
            }
    
            let rect1 = new Rect(100, 50);
            let rect2 = new Rect(25, 33);
    
            console.log("rect1 area " + rect1.getArea());
            console.log("rect1 perimeter " + rect1.getPerimeter());
    
            console.log("rect2 area " + rect2.getArea());
            console.log("rect2 perimeter " + rect2.getPerimeter());

 
      
              
/* <---------following code doesn't work----------> */
 
 

 function Rect (width, height) {
                this.width = widthl
                this.height = height;
    
                this.getArea = function () {
                    return this.height * this.width;
                }
    
                this.getPerimeter = function () {
                    return this.height * 2 + this.width * 2;
                }
            }
    
            Rect.prototype.showStats = function (element) {
                console.log("rect2 area " + rect2.getArea());
                console.log("rect1 perimeter " + rect1.getPerimeter());
    
                console.log("rect2 area " + rect2.getArea());
                console.log("rect2 perimeter " + rect2.getPerimeter());
            }
    
            let rect1 = new Rect(100, 50);
            let rect2 = new Rect(25, 33);
    
            rect1.showStats();
            rect2.showStats();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Rect (width, height) {
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
}

Rect.prototype.getArea = function () {
return this.width * this.height;
}

Rect.prototype.getPerimeter = function () {
return this.width * 2 + this.height * 2;
}

Rect.prototype.showStats = function () {
    console.log(this.getArea());
    console.log(this.getPerimeter());
}
    
let rect1 = new Rect(100, 50);
let rect2 = new Rect(25, 33);
    
rect1.showStats();
rect2.showStats();
```

Basically, you want to make the methods a property of `prototype` and then define a function to do what you need it to do.